# How to make an alphabetically ordered index using imakeidx package?

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

I am creating a [thesis template](https://github.com/GuriTheoChem/phd-thesis-template)

The problem I am running into while making an index is I want to produce an index page that will look like:

```
Index

P
Picard, 2

W
Warp factor, 11
```

Right now it looks like:
[image: Index Page: Title Index, entry 1- Picard, page 2, entry 2- Warp Factor, page 11]

The relevant code from [preamble.tex](https://github.com/GuriTheoChem/phd-thesis-template/blob/main/src/contents/latex_doc_preamble/preamble.tex) looks like this:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Package for creating index
% Activate hyperlinks for the index
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc=true]
```

The index entries are made in [chapter01.tex](https://github.com/GuriTheoChem/phd-thesis-template/blob/main/src/contents/mainmatter/part1/chapter01/chapter01.tex) and [chapter02.tex](https://github.com/GuriTheoChem/phd-thesis-template/blob/main/src/contents/mainmatter/part1/chapter02/chapter02.tex) as:

```
\index{Picard}
```

```
\index{Warp Factor}
```

The index is finally printed in [main.tex](https://github.com/GuriTheoChem/phd-thesis-template/blob/main/src/main.tex) as:

```
% Index
\clearpage
\phantomsection % To correct the anchor toc index to the index page. Otherwise, the toc index takes user to the last section of the appendix chapter before this.
\printindex % Print the index
```

Would appreciate any solutions.

Edit - 16/03/2024 9:PM CET:

Updated MWE:

The main file's location is `src/main.tex` and it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\input{src/contents/latex_doc_preamble/preamble.tex}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
    \part{Part 1}

    \chapter{Chapter 01}
    \section{section 1}
    \paragraph*{}
    \blindtext \index{Picard} Picard.

    \chapter{Chapter 02}
    \section{section 1}
    \paragraph*{}
    \blindtext \index{Warp Factor} Warp Factor.

    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendix title}
    \section{section 1}
    \subsection{}
    \paragraph*{}
    \blindtext

    \clearpage
    \phantomsection % To correct the anchor toc index
    \printindex % Print the index

\end{document}
```

The Preamble file's location is `src/contents/latex_doc_preamble/preamble.tex` and is:

```
\title{MWE}
\author{Some Author}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Generates dummy text for testing purposes
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Package for creating index
% \makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc=true]
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc=true,options=-s myindexstyle]
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Include table of contents, list of figures, etc., in table of contents
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Enhancements for hyperlinks and cross-references
```

The pdf file location after compiling would be `build/main.pdf` and is compiled using `latexmk` as follows:

```
latexmk -pdf -output-directory=build src/main.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippets be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sure. I'll edit in a MWE in a bit. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the horrible image which is a feature of the newest version of Okular/KDE.

[image: index separated into letters etc.]

`imakeidx` docs pages 15-16:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myindexstyle.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix
 "\\bigskip\\par\\penalty-50\\textbf{"
heading_suffix
 "}\\\\[\\medskipamount]"
symhead_positive "Symbols"
symhead_negative "symbols"
numhead_positive "Numbers"
numhead_negative "numbers"
delim_0 ",\~"
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\title{MWE}
\author{Some Author}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Generates dummy text for testing purposes
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Package for creating index
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc=true,options=-s myindexstyle]
\usepackage{tocbibind} % Include table of contents, list of figures, etc., in table of contents
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Enhancements for hyperlinks and cross-references

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{Part 1}

\chapter{Chapter 01}
\section{section 1}
\paragraph*{}
\blindtext \index{Picard} Picard.

\chapter{Chapter 02}
\section{section 1}
\paragraph*{}
\blindtext \index{Warp Factor} Warp Factor.

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix title}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{}
\paragraph*{}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\phantomsection % To correct the anchor toc index to the index page. Otherwise, the toc index takes user to the last section of the appendix chapter before this.
\printindex % Print the index

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for this MWE. In my project structure, the `main.tex` file is in the `src` folder. and the preamble is `src/contents/latex_doc_preamble/preamble.tex`.  I use `latexmk` to compile the project and put it in a build directory using `latexmk -pdf -output-directory=build src/main.tex`. It doesn't work in this case. I will update the main question and MWE as such.

Comment: @Guri 'doesn't work' isn't much to go on. Building in another directory is known to be problematic in lots of cases. It's not clear from your edit what you did with `myindexstyle.ist` but, obviously, `makeindex` has to be able to find it.